# SwiftUI - Misaligned Rectangles when Animating Size of ZStack

Tags: swiftui

I'm creating a custom "Disclosure Group" in SwiftUI, that implements a "swipe to delete" kind of function. It works by having two rectangles stacked on top of each other, and the one on the bottom is the red "delete" button you see when you swipe. I also have a boolean value that flags whether or not the component is "expanded," i.e, having larger size. Here is a video of what this looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the component expands in size when tapped, and shows a red "delete" button when dragged. But, when unexpanding the component, **you can see that part of the delete rectangle shows on the bottom.** Below is the implementation, and I'm not sure why the two rectangles don't completely stick together. Does anyone know how I can avoid this glitch?

MRE:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 30) {
            TestDisclosure()
            TestDisclosure()
            TestDisclosure()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct TestDisclosure: View {
    @State var expanded: Bool = false
    @State var isDeleting: Bool = false
    @State var horzdrag: CGFloat = 0 // the horizontal translation of the drag
    @State var predictedEnd: CGFloat = 0 // the predicted end translation of the drag

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)

            label
                .clipped()
                .offset(x: getOffset(horzdrag: horzdrag))
                .animation(.spring(), value: horzdrag)
        }
        .offset(x: isDeleting ? -400 : 0)
        .animation(.spring(), value: isDeleting)
        .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    onDragChange(gesture: gesture)
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                    onDragEnd()
                }
        )
        .cornerRadius(15)
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                expanded.toggle()
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: expanded ? 150 : 85)
        .clipped()
    }

    private var label: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.teal)

            VStack {
                HStack {
                    Text("Test")
                    Spacer()
                    Text("1 unit")
                    Text("12 units")
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
        }
    }

    private func onDragChange(gesture: DragGesture.Value) {
        horzdrag = gesture.translation.width
        predictedEnd = gesture.predictedEndTranslation.width
    }

    private func onDragEnd() {    
        if getOffset(horzdrag: horzdrag) <= -400 {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                isDeleting = true
            }
        }

        horzdrag = .zero
    }

    // used to calculate how far to move the teal rectangle
    private func getOffset(horzdrag: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        if isDeleting {
            return -400
        } else if horzdrag < -165 {
            return -400
        } else if predictedEnd < -60 && horzdrag == 0 {
            return -80
        } else if predictedEnd < -60 {
            return horzdrag
        } else if predictedEnd < 50 && horzdrag > 0 && (-80 + horzdrag <= 0) {
            return -80 + horzdrag
        } else if horzdrag < 0 {
            return horzdrag
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not pull enough to the left, so it is not deleted and returns to its position, the same click is triggered. I don't quite understand this implementation, you can do the same in a standard List without using drag and hardcoded with offset values

Comment: That is not the issue. As you can see in the video, the issue is that when the group unexpands, the two rectangles don't align, so you can see the red rectangle on the bottom. I want the two rectangles to animate together so that you can ONLY see the red rectangle on the right, rather than on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like interference of same animation (spring in this case) applied to different properties, `cause effect is observed when tap (collapse) is applied when drag (offset) is not yet finished.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, but the workaround is to use type of different animations.

Here is a fix - use `default` instead of `spring`.
Tested with Xcode 13.3 / iOS 15.4

```
label
    .clipped()
    .offset(x: getOffset(horzdrag: horzdrag))
    .animation(.default, value: horzdrag)     // << here !!
```